# Display vector in R with a defined viewport

Tags: r, vector

I want to display a vector consistently in different R environment.

For example, for a vector like this

```
c(1:30)
```

will display 24 values per row

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
[25] 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

and not

```
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Can you expand your question to specify what different environments you are talking about and how you want them displayed?

Comment: Have you looked at `?options` ? There's really a whole book an different custom options.

Comment: my goal is to like controlling viewport consistently... so that it always display in 24 values per line. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is to use `options()` to configure the width of the results window:

```
options(width = 75)
c(1:30) 

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
[24] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for!

Comment: Try this with `c(1030:1060)` - it won't break at every 23th column.

Comment: How come it won't break?

Comment: @Dino: Try it out.

Comment: I think it is ok, as it is consistent in reproducing the display